# Link route to single object, without id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have prepared this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gonvaled/GhDzG/). This is the code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 13,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    // put your routes here
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    email : DS.attr('string'),
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [{ id: 'me', name: 'Max Smith', email: 'max.smith@email.com' }];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.User.find();
    }
});
```

And this is the template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each model}}
    <div class="form_labels_wrapper">
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Id:</dt>               <dd>{{id}}</dd>
        <dt>Name:</dt>             <dd>{{name}}</dd>
        <dt>Email:</dt>            <dd>{{email}}</dd>
      </dl>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

What I want to do is to display the data of a single user. The opbject has no id (it represents the logged in user, which is session related, and has no id visible for ember). Instead, I am forced to create a list of users (with one user), and give it a fake id (`me`). This makes no sense in my application.

I would like to use this template, but I have no idea how to configure ember for this:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="form_labels_wrapper">
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Name:</dt>             <dd>{{name}}</dd>
        <dt>Email:</dt>            <dd>{{email}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </script>
```

With this fixture:

```
App.User.FIXTURES = { name: 'Max Smith', email: 'max.smith@email.com' };
```

Note that this is a single element, and that I am not looping through the models with `#each`, because this should not be a list: there is only a single element.

Ember refuses to accept this. What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can returning an array of records from the `model` hook, as a result ember is generating an `ArrayController` for it, which expects it's `content` to be an array.

Change the `model` hook to return the single record. For instance using *me* as the id.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.User.find('me');
    }
});
```

Then your template works. See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhDzG/2/).

Comment: Thanks, although not exactly what I wanted. My request is going to `api/me`, and the server replies with the data of the logged in user. I will have to provide a new api endpoint `api/users/me` (lucky me I can change the server side). This is awkward, since I *only* have the `me` user. But slowly I am getting convinced that it is not possible to do this otherwise with ember. It seems ember really needs to do "find all", or "find object with id". It is not possible to tell ember: "here you have an object, there is only one of its kind, it has no id, but this is fine".